# Jquery Update Trigger dont Work

Tags: jquery

On jquery-1.6.1.min.js trigger works:
[image]

But on jquery-1.11.3.min.js dont work anymore when I click the element:
[image]

The log above show´s some difference between am I missing something?

```js
$(keyF2).bind("click", function(){
    var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
    e.keyCode = 113;
    $('input[aria-label*=Text ]').trigger(e);
    console.log(e)
});
```

Comment: edit your code, add the missing html and make the snipped work. that will help you get answers

Comment: as an aside, jquery recommend you use event.which (http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) instead of event.keyCode

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7 use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`